# dot vs bracket notation in jquery method chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

Suppose that I have a long chain of jquery methods and want to add extra call of one of two methods (e.g. `show` or `hide`) depending on some boolean condition.

There are two ways to do it:

1) ***Dot notation***: store the method chain in a variable, then call extra method (resolved by `if...else` construct or ternary operator) with this variable using dot notation.

*Code*:

```
var $tmp = $el._long_()._method_()._chain_();
if (condition) $tmp.show();
else $tmp.hide();
```

2) ***Bracket notation***: append extra call of method (resolved by ternary operator) using square bracket notation.

*Code*:

```
$el._long_()._method_()._chain_()[condition? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

I used to use the first one, especially if `$tmp` variable is used elsewhere. But the second way seems to be more concise though less readable.

What would be the best choice for such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[eslint](http://eslint.org/) prefers [dot-notation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation):

> In JavaScript, one can access properties using the dot notation
>   (foo.bar) or square-bracket notation (foo["bar"]). **However, the dot
>   notation is often preferred because it is easier to read, less
>   verbose, and works better with aggressive JavaScript minimizers.**

IMO, putting tertiary logic inside of bracket's is a little too cute and hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

This question could be generalized for JavaScript at large, rather than jQuery-specific.

The typical reasons to use bracket notation are when:

1. The function/property name you want to reference is variable, in which case brackets can help you keep your code DRY
2. The property/function name has characters making it impossible to access via dot notation.

Your use here seems like a novel variation of the first case-- you're avoiding repeating code by using a variable string value from a ternary operation to specify which function to execute.

It's a trade-off between explicit readability and DRY code, so the "best" choice will be subjective.

For some people, ternary isn't so tough to read. You are `you can read this ? "one of them" : "not one of them"`. You could always throw a comment near any particularly long function chains for the benefit of people who have trouble digesting ternary.