# Conditional reverse() with chain method (using Lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following piece of code:

```
if (this.config.order === 'asc' ) {
  return _.chain(this.rows)
    .sortBy(this.config.orderBy)
    .slice((this.config.page - 1) * this.config.numOfRows, this.config.page 
    * this.config.numOfRows - 1)
    .value()

} else {
    return _.chain(this.rows)
    .sortBy(this.config.orderBy)
    .reverse()
    .slice((this.config.page - 1) * this.config.numOfRows, this.config.page 
     * this.config.numOfRows - 1)
    .value()
}
```

There is a big duplication, because the condition determines if `reverse()` will be used or not.

Is there any way to reduce it for one chunk of `_.chain` call only?

Comment: Read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949500/dot-vs-bracket-notation-in-jquery-method-chaining). It may give clue to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be achievable by using [_.tap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#tap), like this:

```
_.chain(this.rows)
.sortBy(this.config.orderBy)
.tap(this.config.order === 'asc' ? _.noop : _.reverse)
// continue your chain
```

But maybe you can use _.orderBy instead of _.sortBy, since the former allows you to specify sort orders as argument.